# New React with Material-UI Typography and Button component font-weights are not displaying right

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, create-react-app

I have these code on my previous and my latest React applications:

```
<Typography
  variant="h6"
  color="inherit"
  noWrap
>
  h6. Heading
</Typography>

<Button
  type="button"
  size="large"
  color="primary"
>
  Primary button
</Button>
```

Their labels have `font-weight: 500` on both my previous and latest apps. The problem is, on my previous app and Material-UI demos, those labels have a **"bold appearance"**, while on my newly created React app, they just have a "normal font-weight looks" and must have a `font-weight: 550` to have a **"bold text"**.

My latest React application have these dependencies with an `npm` version of 6.8.0:

```
"@material-ui/core": "^3.9.2",
"react": "^16.8.2",
```

Any reason why it's happening? Believe me I already tried to output just a `Typography` and a `Button` component without any parent, and it seems they still appearing with a normal font-weight.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use h6, which hasn't been released on Material UI's stable branch yet (it will be in version 4.0.0).

**Option 1**

You can add `useNextVariants: true` to your MUI theme to use h6 (and all the other typography in 4.0.0) in the meantime:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    useNextVariants: true,
  },
});
```

---

**Option 2**

You could also use `variant="title"` instead of `variant="h6"` if you want a quick fix now, but remember that you'll need to change this when you upgrade to 4.0.0 anyway.  For the quick fix, your code would look like this:

```
<Typography
  variant="title"
  color="inherit"
  noWrap
>
  h6. Heading
</Typography>
```

---

As to why this worked in your older apps, it's hard to say without seeing the code, but you were probably using "next", not the "stable" branch of Material UI.